# CodenameOne :"Path to javac not found" error

Tags: android, javac, build.xml, codenameone, java-home

I start working with CodenameOne tool for multiplatform mobile dev. When I created "hello world" app and tried to build an .apk android file, I received

```
 [echo]       Error! Path to Javac not found! 
 [echo]       Make sure the JAVA_HOME enviroment variable is pointing to the JDK 
 [echo]       or define javac path in build.xml manually!
```

I added JRE reference to the project, but this didn't solve the issue. How can I solve it?

Comment: " Make sure the JAVA_HOME enviroment variable is pointing to the ***JDK*** " - not JRE

Answer (score 1):

Codename One needs to use the actual javac compiler and not ADT since some of our server code has some issues with ADT.

The JRE doesn't contain javac, you need to install a JDK (if you don't have one already) then make sure your OS defines the JAVA_HOME environment variable so it points at the root of the JDK dir (not the bin directory).

If this doesn't work (you might need to restart Eclipse to update environment within the process), then just double click the build.xml file and look for jdk. Update the path to the proper JDK path.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to just setup the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to your JDK directory