# JDK 11 as JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, codenameone

Can the JAVA_HOME environment variable refer to JDK 11 (e.g. jdk-11.0.8) while running Codename One applications under Eclipse 2020-06?

Or does it need to point to JDK 8 (e.g. jdk-1.8.0_241)?

I am having the following error when I try to run Hello World app under Eclipse 2020-06 when JDK 11 is set to JAVA_HOME:

```
BUILD FAILED
...[shortened for brevity]...\HiWorldPrj\build.xml:106: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241"
```

I am positive JAVA_HOME points to JDK 11 (because I can echo it from command line).

But I think I got this error because tool.jar is removed in JDK versions 9 and up and com.sun.tools.javac.Main used to be under tools.jar?

Comment: How do you echo your JAVA_HOME so that you're positive it points to JDK11?

Comment: Yes echo on command prompt shows that I set it correctly to JDK 11: C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8

Comment: But Eclipse thinks that it is not set to JDK11, instead it thinks it is set to JRE 8 as you see in the build error message...

Comment: eclipse has its own internal compiler settings. Check your Java setup in eclipse.

Comment: I have upgraded "Compiler compliance level" from 1.8 to 11 both from "Windows menu-> Preferences->Java->Compiler" and "Project specific settings"... but I still get the same build error?

Comment: @arastirmaci the compiler version in Eclipse has no influence in which JDK you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes [you can use JDK 11](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/uber-book-is-out-jdk-11.html) but your problem seems that the `JAVA_HOME` is set to the JRE and not the JDK.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659201/codenameone-path-to-javac-not-found-error). The JRE alone cannot compile Java code.

```
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241"
```

Find where your JDK 11 directory is and set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to that path.

However I recommend that you set the Java in the Eclipse configuration tab. You'll find that at "Windows menu -> Java -> Installed JREs".

### Update 1

It seems that Codename One uses `JAVA_HOME`, it is set up in the `build.xml`. So forget what I said about the Eclipse variables for now.

```
<property name="javaHome" value="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
```

Make sure your environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is set to the JDK 11. You can see dos on how to set that [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html).

### Update 2

Also, you'll need to update every `source="1.5"` and `target="1.5"` in the `build.xml` file to either `1.8` or `11`.

Example of the change in the `eclipse.ini`:

```
-vm
C:/Users/evand/Downloads/openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin/jdk-11.0.2/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: How can I set the Java in Eclipse configuration? Some posts say that we can try to set JAVA_HOME in Eclipse from "Windows menu -> Preferences -> Add runtime variables ", but I do not have "Add runtime variables" option under "Preferences" in Eclipse 2020-06?

Comment: @arastirmaci you set up the Java installation in Eclipse in "Windows menu -> Java -> Installed JREs".

Comment: "Installed JREs" are set to JDK 11 as well... because JDK 11 does not come with JRE directory, I set the "Installed JREs" to JDK (not JRE) directory...

Comment: @arastirmaci I've updated the answer, can you check if that works?

Comment: I am positive JAVA_HOME is referring to JDK 11. I have changed "source" and "target" to 11 (they were set to 1.8) in build.xml but this did not solve my problem either :(

Comment: Giorgi Tsiklauri suggests that my Eclipse might be bundled with JDK 8 and I might be able to able to reconfigure it to use JDK 11. Do you know how to do this reconfiguration?

Comment: Yes, try [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) and let me know (I doubt this will work).

Comment: Amazingly this worked!! Thank you very much for your help Evandro Pomatti and @giorgi-tsiklauri :)

Comment: @arastirmaci well go figure ^^'.. glad to help

Comment: Thanks for the **eclipse.ini** tip. I didn't want to change my **JAVA_HOME** environment variable setting, which points to JDK 1.8..

Comment: @amitsriv99 yeah avoid relying on `JAVA_HOME`, best to have everything dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Your `JAVA_HOME` refers to the JRE, and JRE does *not* contain `javac` Java Compiler.

You need to point your JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK, i.e. the root directory of the Java binaries.

If your console prints the address of JDK 11 when you *echo* JAVA_HOME, then it might be that your IDE is configured to override that variable with the JRE directory when you're using that IDE.

Alternatively, your IDE can be using its bundled JRE, and your system might be referring to another Java binaries (JDK, in your case).

Comment: I do not think IDE is configured to override this. Because when I set my JAVA_HOME to JDK 8, I do not receive any error message...

Comment: I clearly said, that it might either override or use its own bundled Java runtime, which you can reconfigure. So you resolved your problem by setting it to Jdk8?

Comment: Yes if I set JAVA_HOME to JDK 8, it works... But I want to use JDK 11 if possible... How can I reconfigure its own bundled Java runtime so that it uses JDK 11? Thank you for your comments!